# Does PHP have a peek array operation?

Tags: php, arrays, stack, queue

I would like to peek at the first element of an array. This operation would be equivalent to this code:

```
function peek($list)
{
  $item = array_shift($list);
  array_unshift($list, $item);
  return $item;
}
```

This code just seems really heavy to me and peek is often provided by queue and stack libraries. Does php have an already built function or some more efficient way to do this? I searched php.net but was unable to find anything.

**Additional note for clarity:**
The array is not necessarily numerically indexed. It is also possible the array may have had some items unset (in the case of a numerically indexed array) messing up the numerical ordering. It is not safe to assume $list[0] is the first element.

Comment: I dont understand what's your trying to get.. you could just look at the first value of the array $list[0]

Comment: `return $list[array_keys($list)[0]]`

Comment: @fadeys.work The array is not necessarily numerically indexed. It is also possible the array may have had some items unset messing up the numerical ordering. Long and short assuming array[0] is the first element is a very bad assumption in php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [current()](http://php.net/current) function will give you the 'current' array-value.  If you're not sure if your code has begun to iterate over the array, you can use [reset()](http://php.net/reset) instead - but this **will** reset the iterator, which **is** a side-effect - which will also give you the first item.  Like this:

```
$item = current($list);
```

or

```
$item = reset($list);
```

EDIT: the above two functions work with both associative and numeric arrays.  Note: neither gives the 'key', just the 'value'.  If you need the 'key' also, use the [key()](http://php.net/key) method to get the current 'key' (current refers to where the program is pointing in the array in the case of the array being iterated over - cf. foreach, for, iterators, etc.)

Comment: Excellent Answer. I appreciate the note about the `key` function. That would have been my next question if it wasn't answered here :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP has a peek function. It is the function end().
This sets the pointer to the last element of the array and returns that value.
If the array is empty, it will return false.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

The other two stack-functions are array_pop() and array_push().

Comment: `end` is the opposite operation to the one described in the question. I believe "reset" would be the correct answer. But if you were using push/pop instead of shift/unshift it would indeed be equivalent to a peek, except for the obvious cavoite that it moves the array pointer to the end of the array.

Comment: @danielson317: you're absolutely right. I overlooked 'the first element'. Reset is the way to go. Do you want to edit my answer?