# How to select the first object in an array (when array[0] doesn't work)?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I just discovered a useful php feature that allows me to sort array in natural order by calling `natsort()`. The challenge is this command does not change the key of the array. For example if I have an array that is

```
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
    [2] => img2.png
)
```

It will output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

This is what I want, but then if I want to output the first element in Array by using Array[0], it will still output `img12.png` instead of the desired `img1.png`.

Is there a different way I can call the object in an array by its index?

I will need the syntax for both php and javascript (unless they are the same).

Comment: I just asked this question a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991041/does-php-have-a-peek-array-operation

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing a for loop over the array but note also that if you were doing a `foreach($array as $value){ ...do something... }` style loop, you will get the elements in the array order regardless of the key order. Each iteration, $value would be equal to the current value from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options to re-index the array:

1. Use `sort()` with `SORT_NATURAL` flag, this re-indexes the array
2. Use `array_values` on the array to re-index the array

Comment: are we limited to only one ? :-)

Comment: @Dagon: Unless you want the quickening and then we have to try and take each others head.